# Elastalert: How to run rule periodically

Tags: python, elasticsearch, yaml, elastalert

We are using Elastalert for alerting on Elasticsearch data. I want to run a rule periodically like rule should run every hour (1AM, 2AM,... 23PM) of a day. We are using below code snippet for the same.

```
name: Test Alert
type: frequency
index: example-index-*
timestamp_field: '@timestamp'
timeframe:
  hours: 1 
realert:
  hours: 1
num_events: 1
use_count_query: true
doc_type: _doc
filter:
  - query:
      query_string:
        query: 'event_type: api_log'
  - range:
      responseCode:
        gte: 400
        lt: 499
alert_text_type: exclude_fields
alert:
  - slack
slack_webhook_url: "<slack_webhook_url>"
alert_subject: "Test Rule \n num_hits = {0} \n num_events = {1}"
alert_subject_args:
  - "num_hits"
  - "num_events"
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong we are doing, what changes we need to require?

Answer (score 0):

Include `run_every: 60` option in your config file or above code snippet.

Then, You can start the elastalert using argument `--start <timestamp>`

Example:

```
python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --start 2021-06-18T01:00:00 --rule example_frequency.yaml
```

The above example to start elastalert use the timestamp of format ISO8601 and is in UTC. You can use your timezone like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS-08:00` (PST).

> Note: It is not necessary to start the elastalert using the `--start` argument. Just including `run_every` option in your config will run the elastalert to query every hour.

More details here:

- [run_every](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html?highlight=run_every#)
- [--start](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html#running-elastalert)